# PHP testing function

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, login-script

I am creating a user login/register form. I am testing the php login form right now.

Im using the function `user_exists` to test to see if the user, the username is found in the database. Whenever I add an "if" statement to test i receive an error that says the page is unable to handle my request. Whenever i remove the IF statement the page displays just fine.

```
<?php


function user_exists($username){

$query = mysql_query(" select count(user_id) From Users WHERE  username = '$username' ");

return (mysql_result($query) == 1) ? true : false;

}

if( user_exists('kwame') === true){
echo 'true';
}

else {
echo ' oh no!';
 }

?>
```

Comment: So open error logs and check for errors there.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128412/sql-injection-is-17-years-old-why-is-it-still-around

Comment: Don't use `mysql` because it is depreciated and will no longer be supported in PHP 7. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead

Answer (score 2):

mysql_result will return a string not an integer
use mysql_num_rows instead

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling your function correctly - it's looking for username and returning a boolean

Change

```
if( user_exists($username) === 'kwame'){
```

to

```
if( user_exists('kwame')){
```

Comment: How did your question just change/get edited while I was typing? and no indicator that it was edited? I just copied / pasted from your question - and now it's different

Answer (score 0):

Here is a documentation of mysql_result():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

You can see what arguments it needs and what it returns:

```
string mysql_result ( resource $result , int $row );
```

Retrieves the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set.